Airgapped Landscape and the USN database
My Google-FU hasn't produced anything useful... so I'm wondering if anyone who is running a manually installed airgapped installation of Landscape (24.04.5) server has figured a way to download/transfer/extract the USN database so that Landscape can report on security vulnerabilities?
The update_security_db.sh cron obviously fails because it can't call home to retrieve the DB.  I was about to pick it apart and see if I can engineer a solution but I figured I'd ask here first since I really don't enjoy re-inventing any wheels.
